# Telegram Webhook called by http:// instead https://

Tags: bots, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I have created Telegram bot, and try to connect it with my web.
I have stuck on **webhook** step.

My app is

- running on Symfony 5.4
- For Bot API i've choosed `klev-o/telegram-bot-api`
- Mysql 5.7
- cloudflare certificate.
- configured webhook:

```php
 Klev\TelegramBotApi\Types\WebhookInfo {#702 ▼
  +url: "https://example.com/api/webhooks/telegram"
  +has_custom_certificate: false
  +pending_update_count: 2
  +last_error_date: 1698934939
  +last_error_message: "Wrong response from the webhook: 301 Moved Permanently"
  +max_connections: 1
  +last_synchronization_error_date: null
  +allowed_updates: null
}
```

Issue:

- When Telegram triggers webhook, he make request on `http://example.com/api/webhooks/telegram` instead `https://example.com/api/webhooks/telegram`

Therefore my api can't proceed webhook action

Request Log:

```php
request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "POST http://example.com/api/webhooks/telegram"" at /var/www/app/public_html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 135 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"POST http://example.com/api/webhooks/telegram\" at /var/www/app/public_html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:135)\n[previous exception] [object] (Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0): No routes found for \"/api/webhooks/telegram\". at /var/www/app/public_html/vendor/symfony/routing/Matcher/Dumper/CompiledUrlMatcherTrait.php:74)"} []
```

May be I have missed something? Some Webhook/Bot/Telegram setting?

I thought that webhook should trigger my API that i have passed for it.
But unfotunatly he decided to trigger it by `http://` protocol, insted `https://`

And I have no idea how to solve it